# How can I stretch columns to fit text programatically with POI Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I'm using POIExcel to create an Excel document and set the appropriate headers programatically, as you can see below. I then add additional rows below in my `printSubnetInfo()` method. What I want to do is make sure the columns are stretched to fit the text when I open the document. Ignore the bolding!

```
String outputs = "\\outputs\\";
String filename = homepath + outputs + customer + ".xls";
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Subnet Information"); 

// Create Excel document header row
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Default Gateway");
rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("CIDR Signature");
rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Netmask");
rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Network Address");
rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Broadcast Address");
rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue("Lowest Address");
rowhead.createCell(6).setCellValue("Highest Address");
rowhead.createCell(7).setCellValue("# of Subnet Addresses");

// Add rows to Excel document
for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum < (defaultGWsList).size(); rowNum++) {
    String defaultGWAddr = defaultGWsList.get(i);
    printSubnetInfo(subnetInfo, defaultGWAddr, homepath, customer, sheet, rowNum);
}

// Create Excel file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNumber);
```

run it after filling in all the data.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I guess for larger numbers of columns you'd want to loop through them. ``for (int colNumber = 0; colNumber <= 7; colNumber++) {sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNumber); }``

Comment: Yep. You have to loop column by column. It can be quite slow for big datasets.